# React submit form on select change event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, submit, antd

I'm using [ant design](https://ant.design/components/form/). I have a form. In that form I have submit button and select dropdown.

when I click submit button it triggers the form submit action.

I need to submit form and get values on select change event.

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xrpzw7wn8q

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer this question in a more general way because it pops in the search results and it may help some people.

To submit a select form on a change event (without a submit button) in React, you have to do two things:

1. use the "onChange" property to fire a function to send the value.
2. in this function, you have to trigger the submit action of the form.

To do number 2, in classical javascript you would grab a reference to the form and then use the submit() method. In React, to grab the form, you can use ["useRef"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). The submit() method is then accessible on the "current" property. Here is an implementation:

```
import { useRef }, React from "react"

export default function SelectOnChange () {
  const selectForm = useRef(null)
  const handleSubmit = () => {selectForm.current.submit()}
  return (
    <form ref={selectForm} method="get" onChange={handleSubmit}>
      <select name="sort" id="sort">
        <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
        <option value="score">Score</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along those lines:

```
<Select allowClear onSelect={ (val, event) => this.handleSubmit(event) }>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback to the `onchange` event of the Ant Design Select component, that could handle the form submit:

```
<Select
  allowClear
  onChange={
    (value) => {
      // your code to submit the form
    }
  }
>
  <Option key={1} value={1}>
    something 1
  </Option>
  <Option key={2} value={2}>
    something 2
  </Option>
</Select>
```

**BUT** from an UX perspective, if the submit button has to be present, it should be it to trigger submitting

Answer (score 0):

Add the [onChange() or onSelect()](https://ant.design/components/select/) from ant design select and access the values from the form in the callbacks.

```
state={
  selectValue : "default value",
  otherFormItemValue: "default other value"
}

handleSubmit = () => {
  serviceCallToSubmitForm(this.state.selectValue, this.state.otherFormItemValue);
}


//In the render() of component

<Select
  onChange={ 
//or onSelect
  (value) => {
    this.setState({selectValue: value}); 
    this.handleSubmit() 
    }
  }
>
  <Option key={1} value={"value 1"}>
    something 1
  </Option>
  <Option key={2} value={"value 2"}>
   something 2
  </Option>
</Select>

<Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
```

Hope this helps and is clear enough.

The handleSubmit function is used to access the form values from the state and submit it.
The onChange function call it used to :
 1. Store the dropdown value in the state
 2. call the handleSubmit function to actually submit in the same action [not recommended UX-wise]

Answer (score 0):

Here is code sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/r00v7x8r7q

Select dropdown item and check console for the respected value.

***Getfield decorator doesn't have onchange option, so remove it and add onchange event to select tag instead of getfield decorator.***

Check ant docs for available options. 
https://ant.design/components/form/

> getFieldDecorator(id, options) parameters